# Hibernate chokes on this HQL cross join

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, hql

After some fiddling with the code below I suddenly get an exception telling "Transaction not successfully started." and I don't seem to get rid of it. Can you spot an error in the Java method?

**Datamodel**

Suggestion: suggestion_id, name, isReceivedNSD, isSetupNSD, isDecidedUHR, meeting_id, ..
Meeting: meeting_id, date
Log: log_id, suggestion_id, ..

What's special here is this:

Controlpanel: controlpanel_id, processMeeting_id (always just one row, containing current choices)

**Java method**

```
public static List<Suggestion> getSuggestion(final int maxResults,
     final boolean isReceivedNSD, final boolean isSetupNSD, final boolean isDecidedUHR,
     final Status status) throws GettingException {
  final Transaction transaction = getSession().getTransaction();
  List<Suggestion> list = null;
  final Query query;
  try {
     final String hql = "select f" //
           + " from Controlpanel p, Log L" //
           + " where L.suggestion.isReceivedNSD = :isReceivedNSD" //
           + "   and L.suggestion.isSetupNSD = :isSetupNSD" //
           + "   and L.suggestion.isDecidedUHR = :isDecidedUHR" //
           + "   and L.status.id = :statusId" //
           + "   and L.suggestion.meeting.id = p.processMeeting.id";
     query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
     query.setParameter("isReceivedNSD", isReceivedNSD);
     query.setParameter("isSetupNSD", isSetupNSD);
     query.setParameter("isDecidedUHR", isDecidedUHR);
     query.setParameter("statusId", status.getId());
     query.setMaxResults(maxResults);
     list = castList(Suggestion.class, query.list());
     transaction.commit();
  }
  catch (final HibernateException e) {
     throw new GettingException("Suggestion list. " + e.getMessage());
  }

  finally {
     HibernateCommon.rollbackIfNeededDuringHenting(transaction);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: Besides the adding of transaction.begin() (thanks, JB!), the select should begin with 'select L.suggestion'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is clear: *Transaction not successfully started*. You forgot to start the transaction:

```
final Transaction transaction = getSession().getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
```

Or simply:

```
final Transaction transaction = getSession().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Geees, how blind was I?  Thanks a lot!